# Remove getRouteKeyName from Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am in the process of trying to clear up a variety of little aspects of a project I inherited and am in the process of removing the odd Route Key Names from the models. I am testing with the easiest model which had the following in it:

```
public function getRouteKeyName(){
        return 'url_string';
    }
```

I just deleted the lines and saved it but unfortunately it returned "Sorry this page could not be found" when using the regular ID, but brought up successfully using the field contents of `url_string`.

The route in web.php uses the following: `/carrier/customer/show/{customer}`

What else do I have to do to remove its dependence on the url_string field?

### Update with controller method

```
public function show(Customer $customer)
        {
            return view('customers.show', compact('customer'));
        }
```

Comment: can you show your route ?

Comment: @rkj - I've added it up above. Thanks!

Comment: did you clear your cache ?

Comment: Yes I’ve cleared my cache through the artisan command.

Comment: try `php artisan route:cache` and `php artisan config:cache` separately

Comment: also check in `RouteServiceProvider`, do you have any `explicit binding` on `customer`

Comment: can you please update your question and include the controller method that is responsible for showing the customer

Comment: @MohammadIstanboli - I've updated it with the controller method as you requested.

Comment: @rkj - I've done as you suggested and still no change, it still wants to use the old `url_string` contents...

Comment: can you try once `/carrier/customer/show/{id}` and in controller `public function show($id)` and then fetch customer. just check does it load. also try another route `/carrier/customer/load/{customer}` does it work ?